# Webdriver error: "No alert is present" after UnexpectedAlertPresentException is thrown

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test a webapp I'm developing. I'm using the Firefox driver against Firefox 22.0.

At one point, a modal dialog may pop up (a Javascript prompt()). If it does, I want to enter some text and then dismiss it (click OK).

Here's the relevant code:

```
try:
    if button.text == "Run":
        button.click()
except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
    alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    print alert.text
    alert.send_keys('8080')
    alert.dismiss()
```

The `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` *is* being thrown. However, as soon as it tries to execute `print alert.text`, I get:

```
`NoAlertPresentException: Message: u'No alert is present'`.
```

If I remove the print statement, it blows up at `alert.send_keys` with:

```
`WebDriverException: Message: u'fxdriver.modals.find_(...) is null'`
```

I don't get it. Isn't the `NoAlertPresentException` by definition contradicting the `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` that was thrown and caused the except block to be executed in the first place?

Edit: Also, I can't for the life of me find any documentation on the `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` in http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html#documentation

Edit 2: This is what I have now:

```
try:
    if button.text == "Run":
        button.click()

        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()

        alert.send_keys('1111')
        alert.dismiss()

 except NoAlertPresentException:
     pass
```

However, I'm still seeing this:

```
WebDriverException: Message: u'fxdriver.modals.find_(...) is null'
```

on the line `alert.send_keys('8080')`. I guess I don't understand why `switch_to_alert()` doesn't throw `NoAlertPresent` if there isn't an alert...which is what I'm assuming the `WebDriverException` is indicating.

Comment: What i can say to you, is that you will get MORE than just only 1 type of error. So, to make more road-warrior you must try to handle the 2 or 3 most common problems, like timeout, not-present, or unexpected. You must import each of them from **selenium.common.exceptions** and also add a **Except NameOfError** block then process it. I see today that i can put more than just one Except , and also learned to **pass** from your code sample :) Loving python and learning it every day.

Comment: You have to surround with Try block that ` alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()`. You're forcing the script to change to an alert that maybe is NOT here. Try this: http://pastebin.com/02RALuGp

Comment: I think the problem with this is that the exception handler removes the alert from the browser. It's a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: Could this be the root cause? A bypassed call to fxdriver.modals.clearFlag_ ... cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568402/how-do-i-manually-mouse-dismiss-a-javascript-alert-and-get-back-the-the-body-o/44592827#44592827

Answer (score 3):

I think Selenium closes unexpected alerts. Apparently you can change how the firefox driver treats unexpected alerts:
[How to handle an Alert with "UnexpectedAlertBehaviour" capability in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913453/how-to-handle-an-alert-with-unexpectedalertbehaviour-capability-in-selenium)

As an alternative, you could check if there is an alert before acting (after all, if you want handle the alert it's not unexpected) like so (Java):

```
try {
  Alert alert = _driver.switchTo().alert();
  //do stuff with alert
} catch (final NoAlertPresentException e) {
  //do non-alert stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I may not be the best python programmer, because i started with it 1 week ago.
I've manage myself to create a small function that will accept ANY alert, and also will do it more alerts.

Chaging the IF to WHILE at line -2 (second from tail) we can handle also consecutive confirmations/alerts.
Using IF you can handle replies of confirm()
Using WHILE you can handle all the alerts().
If the alert is under a timeout, you have to try "bypass" the alert() on the correct moment.

I've manage to add 2 exception handlers, to bypass uknown alerts() and also to stop when no alert() is present.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

os.system("pkill php")
os.system("php -S localhost:2222 alert.html &")

fire = webdriver.Firefox()
fire.get("http://localhost:2222")
global alert

def alert_accept():
  try:
    alert = fire.switch_to_alert()
    print "Aler text:" + alert.text
    alert.accept()
    print "Alert detected, accept it"
    return True
  except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
    print "Hum..., continue?"
    return False
  except NoAlertPresentException:
    print "No alert here"
    return False

while alert_accept() == True:
  alert_accept()
```

You cant test it with any website. I've make a local html with some different alerts to digg a little on that.

HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var c = confirm("Do you like kidding yourself?")
if (c == true) {
  alert("true")
} else {
  alert("You're the kidding master, another alert!")
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var c = confirm("Do you like kidding yourself?")
if (c == true) {
  alert("true")
} else {
  alert("You're the kidding master, another alert!")
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("Running test with timeout")
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){ 
  var c = confirm("Do you like kidding yourself?")
if (c == true) {
  alert("true")
} else {
  alert("You're the kidding master, another alert!")
}
 }, 5000)
</script>
```

Actually, the WHILE nor the IF handles the full page, i guess because the timeout. If you put all at onces it does.

Im pretty sure that this can be done using implicit waits and the expected conditions with a shortest code. If you take a look of the source of alert_is_present you will se nothing than a try:block with return true/false.

Answer (score 1):

For my case I need to click on Upload button without selecting File and check that an alert message is coming or not. 
But in my case while clicking on Upload button the below exception is coming 
    selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: 
    Message: Modal dialog present
In my case alert.accept or alert.dismiss is not working
So, I did to press Tab and select the Upload button and Press Enter Key through Python Code. Its working perfect.