# Python: UnexpectedAlertPresentException

Tags: python, selenium

I updated my chrome to the latest version a few days ago, and already downloaded the latest ChromeDriver 2.43, then:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

I got the error when I tried to send keys:

```
no="192"
blank = driver.find_element_by_id("PC1_PageSize")
blank.clear()
blank.send_keys(no) #error happened
```

error said:

```
UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
```

I used to run them in the old version and had no problem. How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913453/how-to-handle-an-alert-with-unexpectedalertbehaviour-capability-in-selenium

Comment: @TheInfectedDrake I've tried the last one, but it said cannot import UnexpectedAlertBehaviour

Comment: @Lara19 Which WebDriver variant are you using? Update the question with the code block you are using to configure the WebDriver instance.