# Selenium Webdriver: UnexpectedAlertPresentException

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Is there a way to close this alert? I tried using drier.switch_to_alert().dismiss() but it doesn't work.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.NAME,"nickname").send_keys(username+str(x)+Keys.ENTER)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 246, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: {Alert text : 
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55917d605919 <unknown>
```

Code:

```
for x in range(bots):
  driver.get('https://kahoot.it?pin='+gamepin)
  driver.find_element(By.NAME,"nickname").send_keys(username+str(x)+Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: You have a **gamepin** handy?

Comment: You might try setting unhandledpromptbehaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700388/how-to-set-unexpectedalertbehaviour-in-selenium-python

Comment: @DebanjanB I just added the pin into a variable at the top